# Why do we use Parent Class reference for overriding in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

```
class Father {
    void name() {
        System.out.println("This is father");
    }

    void details() {
        System.out.println("He is the head of the family");
    }

    void traits() {
        System.out.println("He loves everyone");
    }
}

class Son extends Father {
    @Override
    void name() {
        System.out.println("This is the son");
    }

    @Override
    void details() {
        System.out.println("He is the youngest one in the family");
    }
}


public class overridingDoubt {
    public static void main(String... args) {

        System.out.println("Father type ref");
        System.out.println("******************");
        Father obj = new Son();//This raises my doubt
        obj.name();
        obj.details();
        obj.traits();

        System.out.println("\n \n Son type ref");
        System.out.println("******************");
        Son obj1 = new Son();
        obj1.name();
        obj.details();
        obj.traits();       
    }
}
```

Both the references are achieving the same results too.
I just want to know a real life scenario where using Parent class reference is of utmost importance.

I've been told a scenario where we would want to store all the objects in a List 
and using Parent class reference would let us achieve that.

Comment: It seems like the code is trying to teach about polymorphism...

Comment: Yes.. It is.. And that's the reason why I wanna know what's the point in using Parent type references when we can simply achieve the same thing using child type references.

Comment: OK, I put up an answer try to further elaborate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store the items using generics, or if you want to define a Type which may be any child class, depending on the code. If you want to check that all objects are an instanceof a given parent class etc.

E.g. If you simply want a list of people, who can be any class extending Person you can have

```
List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

Then in your code say you want to have a father and two sons, who each extend Person you can add these to the list

```
list.add(new Father()); //Etc.
```

Then you could for example iterate through the list printing the details.

```
for(Person p: list){
    p.details();
}
```